# How do I use grep to search for strings that exist both on single lines and multiple lines?

Tags: grep, sql, pcregrep

I am searching large amounts of SQL scripts for data dependencies, but due to variations in the scripts, I have encountered an interesting problem.

If I am searching for the word `FROM`, it only returns the line that the word is on. So the following would only print the first and third line while I need the first as well as the third and fourth together. Any help would be appreciated!

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1

SELECT *

FROM

TABLE 2
```

Comment: Yes, exactly this is the point of `grep`: finding lines that contain a word. - What output did you expect? Did you read `man grep`?

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to parse SQL code; the first suggestion I have is http://www.sqlinform.com/sql_formatter_online.html -- then once the code is in the same format, you'll have better chances using UNIX text processing tools to find the data you want.

Comment: Edit your question to supply specific examples of the SQL code, and specific examples of the data you wish to extract and why, and you'll get a better answer quicker. Are the SQL fragments in individual files, embedded in other code, etc?  As it stands, the question is too general.

Comment: http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/list.html may be another way to convert code 'offline' instead of through a website.

Comment: `sed -en '/SELECT/,/FROM/p' /path/to/file.sql` might do what you need perhaps.

Comment: @DopeGhoti: I suggest to remove `-e`.

Comment: I know that in some flavors of `sed`, `-e` is implied, but why would it be harmful in this instance?

Comment: @DopeGhoti: `-e` expects a script and your script is named `n` and your file is named `/SELECT/,/FROM/p`. Or swap `-e` and `-n`.

Comment: It expects a path to a script _or a sed expression_.  Try `echo foo | sed -e 's/foo/bar/'`.  But yes, `sed -en` does not work while `sed -ne` does; I cannot edit my comment to reflect this, however.

Answer (score 0):

SQL statements are usually ended by `;`.

Using `awk` we could use this fact to read `;`-delimited records and test each one for the presence of the sting `FROM`. If such a record is found, we can compress all consecutive spaces into single spaces, change all newlines into single spaces, and output it:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { RS = ";" } /FROM/ { gsub("\n+|  +", " "); print }' statements.sql
```

Testing this with the following file

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1;

SELECT *

FROM

TABLE2;
```

results in

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
 SELECT * FROM TABLE2
```